# Getting last inserted row in access using php

Tags: php, ms-access

I'm inserting into an Access database via PHP but I'm struggling to get the ID of the last inserted row. I have had this working previously but our server broke and I've had to re-write it, but it doesn't return - I'm sure this is how I did it:

```
$idquery = "select @@IDENTITY from [Businesses]";

try{
    $rs = $conn->execute($query);

    $idReturned = $conn->execute($idquery);

    echo json_encode($idReturned); 
} catch(com_exception $e){
    echo($e);
}
```

The insert is successful but the `json_encode($idReturned);` is blank, any idea why?

Comment: You didn't show the value of `$idquery`

Comment: `$idquery = "select @@IDENTITY from [Businesses]"`. It's the value of `$query` that's unknown.

Comment: It seems that `select @@IDENTITY` needs no table name, though I'm not sure whether removing the table name will fix the problem.

Comment: @ChrisLear the value of $query is irrelevant, it's inserting fine into the database it's just the id im trying to get.

Comment: @ChrisLear thanks but removing the table name didnt solve :(

Answer (score 0):

Are you using PDO?

If you are, you can do the following:

```
$id = $con->lastInsertId();
```

Comment: i get exception 'com_exception' with message 'Source: ADODB.Connection
Description: Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Assume $dbh connection handle is already established

$sql = "INSERT INTO business (name) VALUES ('BUS')";

$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);

$sth->execute();

$lastId = $dbh->lastInsertId(); //This is where you get last inserted ID

?>
```

Depends on the DB provider, there might be a situation that you need to set the "Primary key" for that table

Comment: I get exception 'com_exception' with message 'Source: ADODB.Connection
Description: Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another